# Getting a field value from pipe in outside the pipe in Hadoop Cascading

Tags: hadoop, cascading

Regarding above subject, is there any way to get the value of a field from a pipe. And use that value outside the pipe's scope in Hadoop Cascading? The data has delimiter as '|':

```
first_name|description

Binod|nothing
Rohit|nothing
Ramesh|abc
```

From above pipe I need to get a value from the description, whatever that is ***'nothing'*** or ***'abc'***.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop Cascading is developed with a concept of creating real case scenario by flowing data between pipe and executing parallely it over Map-Reduce Hadoop system.

Execution of java program is unnecessary to depend with rest of the cascading flow (from creating source tap to sink tap), and what Hadoop Cascading does is: it executes those two different processes in different **independent JVM instances** and they will be unable to share their values.

Following code and its output shows brief hints:

```
System.out.println("Before Debugging");
m_eligPipe = new Each(m_eligPipe, new Fields("first_name"), new Debug("On Middle", true));
System.out.println("After Debugging");
```

**Expected ouput:**

```
Before Debugging
On Middle: ['first_name']
On Middle: ['Binod']
On Middle: ['Rohit']
On Middle: ['Ramesh']
After Debugging
```

**Actual output:**

```
Before Debugging
After Debugging
...
...
On Middle: ['first_name']
On Middle: ['Binod']
On Middle: ['Rohit']
On Middle: ['Ramesh']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to say. Do you to mean to extract the value of field `${description}` outside the scope of the pipe. If possible something like this in pseudo code.

str = get value of description in **inputPipe** (which is in the scope of the job rather than function or buffer)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want: you have a pipe with one field, that is the concatenation of ${first_name} and ${description}. And you want the output to be a pipe with field that is ${description}.

If so, this is what I'd do: implement a [function](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/operation/Function.html) that extracts description and have your flow execute it.

You function (let's call it ExtractDescriptionFunction) should override method operate with something like this:

```
@Override
public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, FunctionCall<Tuple> functionCall) {
  TupleEntry arguments = functionCall.getArguments();

  String concatenation = arguments.getString("$input_field_name");
  String[] values = concatenation.split("\\|"); // you might want to have some data sanity check here
  String description = values[1];

  Tuple tuple = functionCall.getContext();
  tuple.set(0, description);
  functionCall.getOutputCollector().add(tuple);
}
```

Then, in your flow definition, add this:

`Pipe outputPipe = new Each(inputPipe, new ExtractDescriptionFunction());`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is "Can we extract that description in outside the pipe? By above function the description is extracted but that is still within the pipe. I want to extract that description and want to use as a condition outside the pipe like: if(description!=null){something;} (if we can't extract what is the reason?)".

Comment: I don't think cascading supports defining flow at runtime. The whole data set shares the same pipe. That being said, what might help is a filter. In flow definition, you can have something like:

`Pipe descriptionNullPipe = new Each(inPipe, new CheckDescriptionIsNullFilter());`   
`Pipe descriptionNotNullPipe = new Each(inPipe, new Not(new CheckDescriptionIsNullFilter()));`